# converting google map to pdf in coldfusion

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, google-maps-api-3

Given that coldfusion is server side and javascript is clientside, is there anyway to convert a google map to a pdf using coldfusion?

Comment: Maybe with static api. But I would first investigate whether it is allowed allowed under the terms of use. Not sure.

Comment: @James Hill using coldfusion 8

Comment: @Nate can you elaborate/explain?

Comment: Might not work, but easy to test to find out : <cfdocument format=”pdf” filename=”demo1.pdf” overwrite=”true”><cfhttp url="yourMapPage.cfm"/><cfoutput>#cfhttp.fileContent#</cfoutput><cfoutput></cfdocument>

Comment: BTW, if youre just wanting a map image, I know google provides an API for doing exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try static google map to embed map in pdf. Static map generate image file which will easily added thorough cfdocument. I haven't tried but it should work...

For more detail see 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest wkhtmltopdf.  You give it a --javascript-delay of something like 800ms, and you're good to go.

wkthmltopdf is a command line app that runs on a variety of OSes.

Comment: Just curious: why the down vote?  Given the same HTML file you'd serve to a client, wkhtmltopdf will evaluate all the script and convert the html (as modified by script) to PDF.  What's not to like?

Comment: And wkhtmltopdf is a commandline app.  Says so right there in my reply.  Can't CF call the command line?  My question stands.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1. Create a page that correctly loads the map that you want to convert to a pdf.
2. Use the [cfdocument tag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_05.html) to create the pdf. Something like this: `<cfdocument format="pdf" src="[url to your page]" ... />`

Be sure to test thoroughly. cfdocument **isn't** known for it's ability to properly handle CSS.

**NOTE:** Be sure to check Google's terms of service before you do this.

Comment: Check their terms of service as well. Just to make sure such copying is allowed. IIRC the static api had some limitations.

Comment: @Leigh, Agreed and added to my post!